# How to find out in which version of Node.js was certain commit / pull request released

Tags: node.js

For example, I'd like to find out in which version(s) of Node.js shipped pull request:

[child-process: support any shells on Windows](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/21943) .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe grepping [changelogs](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/doc/changelogs).

GitHub search doesn't seem to be too good for that: [example](https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?q=path%3Adoc%2Fchangelogs%20windows&unscoped_q=path%3Adoc%2Fchangelogs%20windows).

Sourcegraph might be a good online tool to do that: [example](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=repo:%5Egithub%5C.com/nodejs/node%24%20file:doc/changelogs%20windows).

In my case, I would grep for PR number, e.g., `21943`.